# Off-topic categories

Tags: support

When I try to flag a question off-topic, I can't find any way to flag it "not about math". For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435020/how-important-is-physical-exercise-to-math-study-research is off-topic, not because it's homework or belongs on one of three other SE sites or is too broad, but because it's about exercise physiology rather than mathematics. How do I flag that?

Comment: There *is* a [Physical Fitness](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange...  :)

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: I'm only ever offered stats, physics, and the programming one...

Comment: Maybe it's a reputation thing, but don't you have the option to flag it as "needs moderator attention" and then fill in a reason?

Comment: Well, yes, but I thought it best to choose the most precise option and I had no idea that there even was an appropriate SE site.

Comment: In my close dialogue, I have an option "Off-Topic > This question is not about mathematics within the scope defined in the help center". The same option appears when taking the flag route.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: yes, but when I click on that, I'm forced to choose further inapplicable options.